# Rename row index in Python

Tags: python, pandas

How can I do to replace what is marked in red by row 0 (Image 1)? I tried with `index_col = 0`and  `header=0` but the result is different from what I want

[image: Image 1]

Comment: Please convert this to a running example that loads a dataframe so we have something to work with and can test an answer.

Comment: I have only used this `df= pd.read_excel(r'Ubication\file name.xlsx', sheet_name= 'sheet name', nrows= 64, skiprows= 4, usecols= range(20)` .

Comment: You could make a sample dataframe of, say, 3 x 3 elements - perhaps by `df.to_csv` plus a moment spent in a text editor and make something that we can use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example, column name is taken from row 1

```
df = pd.DataFrame( {'a': ['b','c']})

df.columns = df.iloc[0].tolist()
```

This doesn't remove row 0, so if you want to drop that you can go:

```
df = df.iloc[1:]
```